# Filtering by annotated field of a related model

Tags: python, django

I am calculating a field on the fly (=not storing in the DB) and need to filter a related model by that field.

My questions are as follows:

1. Any ideas how can I filter over related fields that are calculated?
2. I would like to understand how Django handles queries (e.g. whether / if / when it is returning a QuerySet and operating on that or if it's hitting the DB directly). If someone could point out to me the relevant documentation, that would be much appreciated!

**Additional information**

My Models (models.py)

```
from .managers import StackManager, PartManager
class Build(models.Model):
    ...

class Part(models.Model):
    build = models.ForeignKey('Build', models.CASCADE, related_name='parts')
    x_min = models.FloatField()
    x_max = models.FloatField()
    y_min = models.FloatField()
    y_max = models.FloatField()
    z_min = models.FloatField()
    z_max = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.FloatField()
    objects = PartManager()

class Stack(models.Model):
    build = models.OneToOneField('Build', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='stack')
    height = models.FloatField()
    objects = StackManager()
```

My Model Managers and QuerySet Managers (managers.py)

```
class StackQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def calc(self,**kwargs):
        valid_parts = self.filter(
            build__parts__y__lte=F('height'),
            ) \
        .annotate(
            total_built_parts_volume = Sum(F('build__parts__volume'))
        )
        return valid_parts

class StackManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StackQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class PartManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()\
                .annotate(
                    x = F('x_max') + F('x_min'),
                    y = F('y_max') + F('y_min'),
                    z = F('z_max') + F('z_min')
                )
```

What I am trying to call

```
Stack.objects.get_calc()
```

- Because the "y_min" and "y_max" could easily change, I want to keep
  the "y" as a computed field. However, I need "y" also in other
  calculations and this doesn't seem to be possible as I am getting

  > Related Field got invalid lookup: y
- I have already moved the fields from properties (@property in model)
  to a custom Model Manager, but this doesn't seem to help either. It
  seems to me that filter and F() objects are directly hitting the DB
  without returning a QuerySet, but I cannot even confirm this as I
  didn't manage to find relevant documentation.
- As an additional note, I can't import Models into .managers.py file
  as this will cause a circular reference...

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to get aggregated sum of volume for parts for which stack height is less or equal to  y_max+y_min?

Comment: @iklinac yes, exactly!